# Initialize array of AudioSource c# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can i initialize an Array of AudioSource to a script and how can I add Value to that Array of AudioSource? I'm Using Unity3d and C# lang

please help...

Answer (score 0):

You can try Resources.LoadAll function I believe. This function loads all the resources from a directory if I remember correctly. For more information here is the doc page for the function

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAll.html